How to create logs from Streamlit app to Azure with OpenTelemetry?
I'm trying to use OpenTelemetry to send logs from a Streamlit app to Azure.
I followed the Azure documentation for OpenTelemetry, tried different methods but it's not working. I'm not receiving logs in Azure when running the App in localhost/dev. I checked the OpenTelemetry documentation and noticed that Flask, Django, and FastAPI are mentioned here as supported frameworks but there is no reference to Streamlit in the complete list of libraries for supported frameworks.
Can someone tell me if it's possible to use OpenTelemetry with Streamlit? And if so, how to use it to send logs to Azure?
I tried the methods described in the Azure documentation for OpenTelemetry, but it didn't work. I was expecting to receive logs in Azure Application Insights but the logs aren't reaching there.
Thanks in advance!

Are you getting any error?

@Jose, please specify the language (Java/.NET/etc.).

Did the below answer worked @José Cordeiro?


Can someone tell me if it's possible to use OpenTelemetry with Streamlit? And if so, how to use it to send logs to Azure?

You can use below code to send logs to azure:
import logging
import streamlit as ri_st
from opentelemetry.sdk._logs.export import BatchLogRecordProcessor as blp
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry.exporter import AzureMonitorLogExporter as ame

from opentelemetry._logs import (
    get_logger_provider,
    set_logger_provider,
)
from opentelemetry.sdk._logs import (
    LoggerProvider,
    LoggingHandler,
)
set_logger_provider(LoggerProvider())
rith_exptr = ame(
    connection_string="InstrumentationKey=e99d91;IngestionEndpoint=https://canadacentral-1.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://canadacentral.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=f3ef2c6c-0e0a"
)
get_logger_provider().add_log_record_processor(blp(rith_exptr))

rith_hndlr = LoggingHandler()
rith_lggr = logging.getLogger(__name__)
rith_lggr.addHandler(rith_hndlr)
rith_lggr.setLevel(logging.INFO)

rith_lggr.info("Hello Rithwik, log from Streamlit Info")
ri_st.title("Hello Rithwik, this is Streamlit")
rith_lggr.warning("Rithwik, log from Streamlit WARNING ")
ri_st.write("Streamtlit Description")
rith_lggr.error("Rithwik, log  from Streamlit ERROR")

Package installed:
pip install azure-monitor-opentelemetry
pip install streamlit

Output:
Run Streamlit App:
streamlit run test.py

Logs in Azure:




